# Proper translation for the exotic pets

Tags: translation

exotic pet is translated on iciba as

> 外来宠物

VICE also translated it the same way in a video of theirs, also adding

> 外来物种

And my **absolute** favorite

> 野生猛宠

is there a common well known term for exotic pets? 野生宠物？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the SPCA hong kong used "珍奇品種寵物" for exotic pet.

http://www.spca.org.hk/ch/animal-welfare/welfare-law-development/exotic-pet-laws

click the flag to toggle between traditional chinese & english :)

imo, turtles, or parrots are not fierce. so, 野生猛寵, the "猛" is, not descriptive for certain species of exotic pet

Comment: Exotic pets are not necessarily "rare"吧

Comment: exotic implies it's from distant country, which's not common locally. therefore it's interesting and valuable.

these pets are ordinary, common species in other countries, they're rare, locally.

Answer (score 0):

"Exotic" refers to a species which is not native or indigenous to the owner's locale; and "pet" is a companion animal living with people. So it can be called 异国宠物，见例：异国短毛猫（exotic shorthair）.

Answer (score 0):

`外来物种` sounds right in Mandarin, but it means exotic species. You can simply replace `物种` with `宠物` and to become `外来宠物`.